# Finding average of count(*) returning multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Hi I am trying to calculate average of a result set but i am not able to do so the query which is selecting count(*) returns call count for each day between 1st and 31st january so there are almost 20 rows returned . How shall i calculate average of the result and then assign the value to a variable like SET @abc = ( the query below ) . I am using sql server 2005.

```
SELECT avg(Calls) AS average 
FROM
(
     SELECT COUNT(*) Calls      
     FROM abc 
     WHERE CallDate  BETWEEN '20120101'  AND '20120131' 
     AND datepart(Hh,TranscribeDateTime) = '07' 
     AND datepart(Mi,TranscribeDateTime) BETWEEN '00' AND '59'  
     AND AppID = 123 AND Status ='T' 
     GROUP BY calldate
)
```

And if my approach is wrong please propose one . Thank You

Comment: Your approach looks ok. What is your problem? Does it fail or do you get an unexpected result?

Comment: SQL Server calculates the average of an integer as an integer, rather than a float.  You may want:  `select avg(cast(Calls as float))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing a table alias for the derived table (required in SQL Server) and the assignment statement (also you can't alias the column `AS average` if you are assigning it to a variable)

```
DECLARE @ABC INT;

SELECT @ABC = AVG(Calls)
FROM
(
     SELECT COUNT(*) Calls      
     FROM abc 
     WHERE CallDate  BETWEEN '20120101'  AND '20120131' 
     AND datepart(Hh,TranscribeDateTime) = '07' 
     AND datepart(Mi,TranscribeDateTime) BETWEEN '00' AND '59'  
     AND AppID = 123 AND Status ='T' 
     GROUP BY calldate
) T  /* <-- Alias here */
```

Comment: Nice catch!  Single character fix.